# My viewport camera is orbiting strangely

Tags: 3d-view

In the default screen usually my camera orbits the cube perfectly, but now it orbits like I’m on the end of a sledgehammer swinging, and sometimes it orbits in anyway it wants to. Sometimes it fixes itself but it’s really annoying.

Comment: maybe enable Edit > Preferences > Navigation > Orbit Around Selection?

Comment: maybe select cube and hit [NumPad .]   ?

Comment: @moonboots I tried it but it didn’t work

Comment: @eezacque didn’t work

Comment: does it happen with any file? any version of Blender? maybe share a file with a simple scene...

Comment: @moonboots I noticed it in version 3.3, but even with a 3.2 config it still occurs. Also it does happen in any file, including files made in the previous versions.